# How to translate my Json in HTML with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, json

So I have a huge problem with my backticks. I don't understand why but when I am using them I have an error in my IDE (I am using Brackets).

I already tried directly in my Browser and with NotePad++ but nothing happened.

Do you have some ideas?

So it's my JS code (main.js)

```
var json = [
    {
        type: "radiogroup",
        name: "q1",
        title: "Dans quel secteur d'activités votre entreprise est-elle active ? (lien avec votre code APE)",
        isRequired: true,
        choices: [
            "Industry",
            "Business",
            "Information and communication",
            "Other services activity",
            "All other activities (financial, agricultural activities ....)",
            "Construction",
            "Public sector",
            "Specialized, Scientific and Technical or Administrative and Support Services Activities",
            "Real estate",
        ]
    }, 
    // ...
    {
        type: "checkbox",
        name: "q4",
        title: "Est-ce que vous développer des services numériques pour un usage interne ou externe (vente aux clients) ?",
        isRequired: true,
        choices: [
            "Yes",
            "No",
        ]
    }
];


function surveyTemplate(json) {
    return `<h2 class="question">${json.title}</h2>`;
}

document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = `
    <h1 class="titre">Voici les questions</h1>
    ${json.map(surveyTemplate).join("")}`;
```

And this is my HTML file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./main.js"></script>
    <title>Rolling Code</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Whats the error?

Comment: `json` looks like a regular js object to me. When you are trying to access `json.title`, this will return undefined, as the title property is nested 1 level deeper, only available in the objects inside your `json` array.

Comment: @achacttn The top level `json` variable is an array, but that array is being mapped using the surveyTemplate function, so the function actually receives each object not the whole array so `json.title` will and should exist.

Comment: @dotconnor My bad, I did not scroll down further

Comment: The error I received is : ERROR:Parsing error:Unexpected character '`'

Comment: Its working for me, I just formated and moved the script tab after the div#app tag. After that I get printed the titles in the document

Comment: Worked for me in jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sparebrain/8xbw76q5/
Suspect issue with Brackets IDE (dhilt response below)

Comment: Thanks @user615274 I tried your advise and it's works !

Answer (score 0):

If we are talking about Brackets IDE error then I suppose you need to configure JavaScript linter and the easiest thing you can do is to add following line at the beginning of your main.js:

```
/*jslint es6:true*/
```

Also, there is an option to create `.brackets.json`  config file in the root of your project where you want to have something like this

```
"language": {
    "javascript": {
        "linting.prefer": ["ESLint"],
        "linting.usePreferredOnly": true
    }
}
```

[Here](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/How-to-Use-Brackets#preferences) you can read about Brackets configuration.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! But I tried just to put my script in my HTML file and now it works !

Comment: @ClémentGody It works because now Brackets deals with HTML file only and jslint is not being applied to it. If you add JS file to your project, jslint will hit you again and you'll have to configure it.